# Rockshox Yari fork stuck

Tags: fork, suspension

I have an enduro bike with a Rockshox Yari fork (160 mm travel), and now it won't compress even 10% even with the air side fully open (so 0 PSI pressure there). It seems that something has gone very wrong on the rebound / oil side. It feels as if there was a remote lock on it, but it doesn't have such feature.

I had it serviced one year ago, and in recent months I have used it for commuting and had to store it in sub-zero temperatures at work. But it hasn't been overly wet, so I don't expect corrosion.

When I move it up and down, the oil-side is making sounds as if it is trying to suck air from random places. This happens wheter I am pushing it in or trying to extend it.

Is there any easy fix for this, or will it have to be serviced again?

Comment: At a guess, I expect the seals are damaged and leaking air, so a service kit should help.  Can you do that work yourself ?

Comment: I they were damaged, would it really result in this kind of behavior? It seems that the air doesn't have any place to go, not that it is leaking.

Comment: Where'd you get it serviced at? Something like this sounds like a mechanical failure of some sort, and it could have been caused by improper assembly the last time around. Perhaps a part fell off and is blocking a damper port or something.

Comment: It was serviced by a reputable bike shop, my friend and I have used them for about 15 times in total (servicing our DH front and rear shocks after every season). Well, it seems that a disassembly is required and I don't think I'm willing to do that myself. It is odd that something broke when I haven't even done any rough riding with it.

Comment: +1 for the sheer awe of commuting with a 160mm fork. I've had the same happen to a Lyric but never discovered the culprit.

Comment: It is just 2 km per direction on the direct route :D But during the winter the icy roads get quite rough. FYI I tried "burping" it with a zip tie, there was some hissing and few ml of oil came out from the damper side but it didn't help the situation. Argh, 6 weeks waiting list for the service since the spring is around the corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the fork serviced, they told me that there was a broken seal on the oil side. So nothing major was broken, and now it is good as new!